# How do I access a property in a public method objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have created a class and i am trying to access some of the property inside of a public method but i cant, the compiler doesn't allow, i really need some help.
this is my code, I am counting on you guys.
Is there other ways to do this ?

the .h file

```
@interface DirController : NSObject



+ (void)startCreate;
+(DirController *)getInstace;



@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * nomeDiretorio;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * enderecoUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * nomeUsuario;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * senha;
//@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString * nomeCliente;
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly ) BOOL              isCreating;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSOutputStream *  networkStream;
```

the .m file

```
+ (void)startCreate
{
    BOOL                    success;
    NSURL *                 url;

  //  assert(self.networkStream == nil);      // don't tap create twice in a row!

    // First get and check the URL.

    url = [[NetworkManager sharedInstance] smartURLForString:self.enderecoUrl];
    success = (url != nil);

    if (success) {
        url = CFBridgingRelease(
                                CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, (__bridge CFStringRef) self.nomeDiretorio, true)
                                );
        success = (url != nil);
    }

    // If the URL is bogus, let the user know.  Otherwise kick off the connection.

    if ( ! success) {

    } else {



        self.networkStream = CFBridgingRelease(
                                               CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url)
                                               );
        assert(self.networkStream != nil);

        if ([self.nomeUsuario length] != 0) {
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.nomeUsuario forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName];
            assert(success);
            success = [self.networkStream setProperty:self.senha forKey:(id)kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword];
            assert(success);
        }

        self.networkStream.delegate = self;
        [self.networkStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [self.networkStream open];

        // Tell the UI we're creating.

        [self createDidStart];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the method `startCreate` is not an instance method, it is a **class method**. You can't access instance variables inside class methods.

You can change the `starCreate` method to be an instance method by replacing the + sign for a - sign at the beginning of the method (assuming you know what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

A class method is just that;  a method on the class.   There is no instance to store the state within.

You need to create an instance of your class  (i.e. `MyClass *myThing = [[MyClass alloc] init];`, convert your class methods to instance methods, and then it'll work fine.